# ajax form submit cross server

Tags: ajax, forms, post, get, submit

I have several servers on an intranet. I am passing data from one server to be processed on another server. Attempting to use ajax but I am a noob.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function print(oForm){

var toggle = oForm.elements["toggle"].value;
var ticket_type_id = oForm.elements["ticket_type_id"].value;
var printer_id = oForm.elements["printer_id"].value;
var store_id = oForm.elements["store_id"].value;
var data = oForm.elements["data"].value;

var dataString = "toggle="+ toggle+ "&ticket_type_id="+ ticket_type_id+ "&printer_id="+ printer_id+ "&store_id="+ store_id+ "&data="+ data;
$.ajax(
{
type:"POST", 
url:"http://192.168.12.103/crowncontrol/backend/processes/print.php", 
data:dataString,
success: function(data){
alert("successful");
}
}
);
}
</script>
```

The above URL does not work. 
But if I make the url:

```
"../../../backend/processes/print.php"
```

Which is the same location, it works fine.
Also if I send it via Anchor Get it works fine:

```
href="http://192.168.12.103/crowncontrol/backend/processes/print.php?etc"
```

The reason I am using ajax is, I want my print.php script to run with out the user noticing. The reason I can't use url:"../../../backend/processes/print.php" is because I will be sending information from one server to another servers on my intranet.

Any help would be appreciated. I've spent far too long trying to get it to work on my own.

AFTER help from the answers below instead of the entire ajax code I used:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.12.103/crowncontrol/backend/processes/print.php?callback=?',dataString,function(res){
    //alert('Success');
});
```

also:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can not perform a normal AJAX requests cross-domain requests for security reasons (see the link about same origin policy).

Fortunately for you jQuery includes JSONP request support which uses script tag injection instead of XMLHttpRequest.

Instead of creating and using an xhr object (XMLHttpRequest which is how ajax is done) it creates a script tag with an src attribute set to your URL. it should work.

Try changing your code to :

```
    $.ajax(
{
type:"POST", 
url:"http://192.168.12.103/crowncontrol/backend/processes/print.php?callback=?", 
data:dataString,
success: function(data){
alert("successful");
}
}
);
```

(notice the ?callback=? part)

Here is a [jsonp tutorial for jQuery](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/)

Here is some information about [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and some information about the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't having a lot of luck with my original code. But you pushed me in the right direction. Ended up using :    $.getJSON('http://------/crowncontrol/backend/processes/print.php?callback=?',dataString,function(res){
        //alert('success');

});

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to deal with this problem is to make a script file in your server and then route the requests through that server request.
Use this logic below:

1. Instead of making the AJAX request directly to cross domain, make the AJAX request to a new script on your server.
2. In that script file, get the request and make the required call(to that cross domain address).
3. Then recieve the response from the cross domain server and send it to the client.
4. Receive the result from your own server which has required data.

This diagram shows:

[image]